# Issue with conflicting constraints

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am not sure what I am missing here,  I have been going at this for hours, looks at constant tutorials, and I am still getting an issue with conflicting constraints.  Basically I have a button, and on this button I want to add a new view that is center to the button and the same size.  When I go to apply the constraints, it is telling me that there are conflicting constraints, and I am just not understanding what can be conflicting here.

```
//Create a new view
let selectBorderView = UIView();
//Guarantee there are no constraints attached to it
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(selectBorderView.constraints);
//Add the new view to the button
sender.addSubview(selectBorderView);

//Create constraint selectBorderView.width = button.width        
let constraintEW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: selectBorderView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: selectBorderView.superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
//Create constraint selectBorderView.height = button.height        
let constraintEH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: selectBorderView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: selectBorderView.superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
//Create constraint selectBorderView.centerX = button.centerX        
let constraintCX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: selectBorderView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: selectBorderView.superview!, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
//Create constraint selectBorderView.centerY = button.centerY
let constraintCY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: selectBorderView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: selectBorderView.superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

//add the constraints to the button        
selectBorderView.superview!.addConstraint(constraintEW);
selectBorderView.superview!.addConstraint(constraintEH);
selectBorderView.superview!.addConstraint(constraintCX);
selectBorderView.superview!.addConstraint(constraintCY);
```

Comment: You have to set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to `false`. Right now you have two sets of conflicting constraints, those you added and those created from your resizing mask.

Comment: The link you provided is not working

Comment: It finally came as a link, I dunno if you did an edit or if SO just glitcehd

Comment: yes, that is what was doing it, thank you very much,  couldn't find anything on it

Comment: If you make it an answer I will mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely seeing an error message that says something like:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

If you see that warning, you should set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to `false`:

```
selectBorderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```